# Binding a js event according to mouse position : performance killer or not?

Tags: javascript, events, dom, mouseevent

I've done this :
http://jsfiddle.net/CS273/4/

On this fiddle, when the mouse reaches the right area of the text input, it changes the cursor (pointer) and creates a click event listener. 
When the mouse gets out of the right area, this same event listener is destroyed.

I would call that "on the fly" event listener binding, perhaps it already has a name.

Is it a good thing to do that or not ?

Comment: Seems like it'd be somewhat cheaper to just set/clear a flag, and wrap the code in the handler in an "if" that checks it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All things being equal, you'll probably never notice a performance hit, but this is a somewhat odd way to do what you want.

I'd suggest re-working your HTML so that the 'x' isn't part of the input and you can just attach a normal event handler.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/cwolves/CS273/6/

Comment: Okay for the performance.
Things seems much simplier as you suggest, that's what Google does on its search page...

Answer (score -1):

See this update to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/CS273/5/

I made a floating div that handles the click for you.

Here it is with some color so you see it: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/CS273/7/

The only js you need:

```
$(".hover").click( function(e) {
    $('.filterNameInput').val('').blur();
});
```

You can add `cursor: pointer;` to the css of `.hover` to have it look the same as your current version.

Comment: lol, and your answer is almost the same as mine.  Probably because of the `position:fixed`, makes this a non-reusable example.

Comment: I didn't downvote (I can't) but I would say that fixed position is a bad idea, I already did that, and it was a nightmare to get something equal in different browsers, even with a reset.

Comment: @youyou, just remember that input backgrounds are not applicable in all browsers (they might not work)